# AJAX success serialize form post value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX form submit to post all values using the `serialize()` method so I           get response in the success like this below

```
fullname=muthu&position=tl&status=active
```

This value I want to convert to array so i will try in AJAX success. How can do this? My AJAX code is here:

```
var candiate_form = $('#candiate_form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "function.php",
    data: { candiate_form: candiate_form },
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. What is the issue with your current code?

Comment: serlize string i want convert to array how can do this?

Comment: `data: candiate_form,` instead of `data: { candiate_form: candiate_form },`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert `fullname=muthu&position=tl&status=active` to an array of objects, then try this.

```
str = 'fullname=muthu&position=tl&status=active';
str.split('&').map(function(a, b){
    ret = {};
    ret[a.split('=')[0]] = a.split('=')[1];
    return ret;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if below thing is what you are looking for.

It should be

`data: candiate_form,`

instead of

`data: { candiate_form: candiate_form },`

And in PHP, access like:

`$_POST['fullname']`